# How can the smtp/pop3 client reads the [error] message that the smtp/pop3 server has send to them (in delphi)?

Tags: delphi, email, indy

My server side smtp and pop3 events send [error] messages with ASender : TIdCommand like this :

```
ASender.Reply.SetReply(OK, 'message to send');
```

or

```
ASender.Reply.SetReply(ERR, 'error message to send');
```

So my question is how can this message be read from the smtp/pop3 client ?

Comment: And is there a way for the POP3 client to get the message that the server is not responding or is not working like : 
    try 

      POP3Client.connect; 

    except 

      // how to read the error message ???? 

    end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to learn how exceptions work.

If `Connect()` fails, an exception is raised.  Several different exception types are possible, including `EIdSocketError`, which contains the socket error code.

If a POP3/SMTP command fails, an `EIdRFCReplyError` exception is raised.  The exception contains the server's response code and message.  This information is also available in the component's `LastCmdResult.Code`, `LastCmdResult.NumericCode`, and `LastCmdResult.Text` properties.

Comment: Thanks, Remy Lebeau - LastCmdResult.FormattedReply.Text is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Do not read from `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply.Text`.  Read from `LastCmdResult.Text` instead.  `FormattedReply` is used for generating and parsing replies, not for processing replies.

Comment: Can you provide some code how the SMTP server can send an error message to the SMTP client and how can the client gets it from event :
    SMTPServerMsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;AMsg: TStream; var LAction: TIdDataReply);
to event :
    SMTPClient.Send(myTidMessage);

Comment: @Roman_Bezjak: In the `OnMsgReceive` event, the only way to send an error message to the client is to either set the `VAction` parameter to a value other than `dOk`, or else raise an exception, which `TIdSMTPServer` will then send to the client. Either way, on the client side, `TIdSMTP.Sender()` will raise an `EIdRFCReplyError` exception with the appropriate `Code` and `Text` values.